# removing clicked item from array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexing, splice

I have a click function to make a list of chosen items. Also, I push the chosen items to an array. There is no problem in that part, here is the function.

```
$('#addToCartButton2').click(function(){  

    var toAdd=$("#chooseItem2 option:selected").text();
    var itemNbr2=$("#itemNbr2").val();

    if(toAdd !== defaultSelectFormText && itemNbr2 >=1){
        $('#defaultText').remove();
        $('.col-md-5').append('<p id="items">' + itemNbr2 + ' Adet ' + toAdd + '<span class="extra">Sipariş listesinden çıkarmak için tıklayın!</span>' + '</p>');
        ordersArray.push(itemNbr2 + ' Adet ' + toAdd);
        alert(ordersArray.toString());
    };
});
```

But I also have a function to remove the clicked item from that list. So I want to remove that item also from array when it is clicked. I tried to use splice method but I can not get the index of the clicked item. Here is the remove function.

```
$(document).on('click', '#items', function() {


    $(this).remove();

    var index = ordersArray.indexOf($(this).val());

    alert(index);
    if (index > -1) {
        ordersArray.splice(index, 1);
    }

});
```

How can I get the index of the clicked item in the list?

Comment: ID should be unique. Use Class to bind events for collection of elements. Better, just provide fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, either you make id of items unique or use class instead of id as I done in this solution.

```
$('#addToCartButton2').click(function(){  

    var toAdd=$("#chooseItem2 option:selected").text();
    var itemNbr2=$("#itemNbr2").val();

    if(toAdd !== defaultSelectFormText && itemNbr2 >=1){
        $('#defaultText').remove();
        $('.col-md-5').append('<p class="items"><span>' + itemNbr2 + ' Adet ' + toAdd + '</span><span class="extra">Sipariş listesinden çıkarmak için tıklayın!</span>' + '</p>');
        ordersArray.push(itemNbr2 + ' Adet ' + toAdd);
        alert(ordersArray.toString());
    };
});

$(document).on('click', '.items', function() {

    var index = ordersArray.indexOf($('span:first', this).text());

    alert(index);
    if (index > -1) {
        ordersArray.splice(index, 1);
    }

    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In function to remove the clicked item from that list, make the following changes:

```
$(document).on('click', '#items', function() {

    var index = ordersArray.indexOf($(this).text());

    alert(index);
    if (index > -1) {
        ordersArray.splice(index, 1);
    }
    $(this).remove();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're way of deleting the item is a little to complex.
Why not just use a uniqe ID for each item you're appending and just delete
the item by it's ID ?